# Collaboration desktop sharing - Multiple Mouse

Tags: mouse, remote-desktop, collaboration

I'm using Windows Xp and i'm looking for a software where I can see the screen of a remote desktop and be able to show a second mouse (or pointer of any sort) that I can mouse to just show something.

I want to work with a peer over the net, pretty much like the XP programming method. I find it useful, but it's pretty hard over the internet to do such thing.

I don't want to control the computer, but it would be a plus. All I want is to see the remote desktop and have my pointer (or marker) to point to a line of code that need to be changed or something like.

Do you know any software like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're after something like Microsoft [SharedView](http://www.microsoft.com/downloadS/details.aspx?familyid=95AF94BA-755E-4039-9038-63005EE9D33A&displaylang=en).

It allows sharing applications etc with multiple pointers.

Comment: Sharedview has been dropped by Microsoft.  It still works, but not if you use IE9.

Answer (score 0):

I already used windows messenger, but I don't remember it to be able to show a second mouse pointer. As I don't want to disrupt the person using the computer, it would only be for some indication.

I already google some solution for VNC, but the only one I found is Collaborative VNC and it's only for Unix.